# STM32CubeMx: Is it possible to configure ST controllers using SPL(Standard Peripheral Library)

Tags: stm32

stm32CubeMx software is providing options for configuration only using HAL & LL drivers.Is it possible using Standard Peripheral drivers.

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any tools like  STM32CubeMx to configure controllers using standard peripheral library.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. ST published a [document](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/5e/65/b0/94/13/e4/42/ca/DM00405316/files/DM00405316.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00405316.pdf) which compares SPL with LL and gives advices how to migrate from SPL to LL. SPL development has stopped so it won't be probably supported in ST products.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion K.Koovalsky

Comment: Any other tools available   that configure using standard peripheral library

Comment: Only the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the SPL for "older" stm mcus. BUT you shouldn't go out and learn SPL instead of HAL (LL). It isn't supported and won't be added to in future. Invest your time in using the HAL or it's minimal subset. This will offer perspective in  the future.